# 'greater in number' or 'greater in numbers'?

Tags: quantifiers

What is the difference, if any, between these sentences?

"African-Americans are greater in number."

"African-Americans are greater in numbers."

I want to say that there are more African-American people

Comment: Either sentence is grammatical, given the proper context.

Answer (score 2):

**"African-Americans are greater *in number*" is the correct form for the expression.**

'In number' here specifies *the aspect* in which the African-American people are greater than other kind of people in. Works the same way as 'in size' in "Pigs are greater *in size* than chickens". Consider now "Pigs are greater *in sizes* than chickens". Here, the mistake becomes evident.

'In numbers' can sound correct to some because there is a common phrase in American English, 'by the numbers' and 'by numbers' which, according to the Oxford Dictionary, mean "following simple instructions identified or as if identified by numbers", but isn't.

Comment: I want to say that there are more African-American people. Does it work with these sentences?

Comment: As I said previously, the correct expression for saying that is "African-Americans are greater in number". That's the expression to be used. "African-Americans are greater in numbers" is incorrect and should't be used.

Comment: Okay but you have not answered my second question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. There is no difference between these phrases because the second one is incorrect, thus doesn't mean anything at all. It is not to be used, so it doesn't 'work' with the second one. "African-Americans are greater in number" is the correct form for the expression. This is the one you should use. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: @user43085 - If you want more clarification, you should edit your question and go into much more detail about what you are asking about. I don't even see _one_ question in your question, much less two. More helpful information can be found at our [*Details, Please*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) meta post.